# Calculating limits and integration in an Error-Accumulating Real Numbers field structure...

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation

I am interested to see if anyone can direct me to a text on using limits and integration in the "Error-Accumulating Real Numbers" field structure. This field consists of the real numbers, but the accuracy of a value diminishes as the reported precision increases, so the error associated with a particular value increases as the precision of reporting on that value becomes greater.

How would one go about taking limits and performing integration on such a field? Is it possible?

Comment: You mean like interval arithmetic, or disk arithmetic for complex numbers? In the AD community there are approaches to bound the truncation error in the propagation of truncated Taylor series, e.g., for trust-region methods, it was a research topic in A. Griewank's group.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Lutz. I am trying to feeling my way towards an algebra over the reals that is not precise beyond a certain max bound...